# PHP find array of key values and replace

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically what I need is to search an array and replace its data

*the main idea is to look for data from an old array and verify if they exist in the new array, if there is no add it*

This is my old array

```
$array1 = array(
array('id' => '1','data1' => 'ect bla bla'),
array('id' => '2','data2' => 'ect bla bla'),
array('id' => '3','data3' => 'ect bla bla'),
array('id' => '6','data3' => 'new data'),
array('id' => '100','data3' => 'this data is added if it does not exist in the array')
);
```

This is my new array

```
$array2 = array(
array('id' => '1','data1' => 'new data'),  //example data that are modified
array('id' => '2','data2' => 'new data'),  //example data that are modified
array('id' => '3','data3' => 'new data'),  //example data that are modified

array('id' => '4','data3' => 'new data'),
array('id' => '5','data3' => 'new data'),

array('id' => '6','data3' => 'new data')   //example data that are modified
);
```

in this part I do not know what to put

```
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
     //this is the id.. I imagine that here is where all the magic goes xd
     $value['id']
}
```

I need this result

```
print_r($array2);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [data1] => ect bla bla
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [data2] => ect bla bla
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [data3] => ect bla bla
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [data3] => new data
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [data3] => new data
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [data3] => ect bla bla
        )
   [6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [data3] => this data is added if it does not exist in the array
    )

)
```

Comment: you want add  the index 4 and 5 with id and data3 ?

Comment: I'm sorry with data4 data5

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that is unique among each of the $array1 and $array2 entries?

Comment: id => 6 can never have data => etc bla bla

Comment: Where is ID 7 and what happened to ID 100, so you magically transmute 100 into 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `array_replace_recursive($array2, $array1);`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php

This gives the following output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [data1] => ect bla bla
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [data2] => ect bla bla
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [data3] => ect bla bla
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [data3] => new data
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100
        [data3] => this data is added if it does not exist in the array
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [data3] => new data
    )

)
```

Then to make it unique use

```
array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array3)));
```